# Why is each of my profiles returning their own row instead of rows of 3?

Tags: python, html, css, django

So, I have a for loop that loops through my users profiles and randomly displays a number of them. I should have 3 profiles return for each row, but instead I'm getting each profile having their own row. What am I doing wrong here>

```
{% for profile in random_profiles %}
```

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <img src="{{  profile.photo.url  }}"  width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"  rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: For each profile you are creating a row. The `<div class="row">` tag is inside `for` loop. I guess either you have to use 2 loops one for profiles and other for number of profile in each row Or maintain a count and if count reached to 4 create extra row then reset the count

Comment: thanks, add it to an answer and I'll vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each profile you are creating a row. The  tag is inside for loop. I guess either you have to use 2 loops one for profiles and other for number of profile in each row Or maintain a count and if count reached to 4 create extra row then reset the count. One of the way to achieve the second approach can be -

```
{% for profile in random_profiles %}
  {% if forloop.first or forloop.counter0 % 4 == 0 %} 
    <div class="row">
  {% endif %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <img src="{{  profile.photo.url  }}"  width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"  rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
  {% if forloop.first or forloop.counter0 % 4 == 0 %} 
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```